# How to display column dynamically according to API responce using ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid

Below is code for ag grid and its getting error on " this.gridApi.setColumnDefs(this.columnDefs)" can somebody guide how to resolve this issue:

```
<ag-grid-angular " 
class="ag-theme-balham"
#agGrid
[columnDefs]="columnDefs"
id="newGrid"
[enableSorting]="true"
[enableFilter]="true"
[modules]="modules"
[paginationAutoPageSize]="true"
[rowData]="rowData"
[defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
(gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
[pagination]="true">>
</ag-grid-angular>
```

Am calling this method on GreadReady() as well as ngOnit but showing error on "this.gridApi.setColumnDefs(this.columnDefs)". Actually this.gridAPI getting undefine. and showing error in console ="Cannot read property 'setColumnDefs' of undefined"

```
public getcolumnData()


      {
        let columnDefs=[];
        this.GetGridData();
        let header:any =[];
        Object.keys(this.JSONDATA).forEach(function(key) {
          header.push(key)
        }); 

         console.log("header.........",header)
          columnDefs=[...columnDefs,{headerName:header,field: header  }];

      });
      this.gridApi.setColumnDefs(this.columnDefs)
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gridApi` for the [ag-grid](/questions/tagged/ag-grid) is only available after `onGridReady` event. More details regarding how you could have instance of `gridApi` can be found on almost every ag-grid example.

Reference: [Column Definition Example](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-definitions/#example-column-definition)

Now, what to be done.

- In this case, you don't need to explicitly call `gridApi.setColumnDefs`. While iterating the column details received from server, simply push them inside `columnDefs` of the component. In your template, you have already passed the columnDefs array to the ag-grid.

```
    this.columnDefs = [];
    this.columnDefs.push({
      headerName: header, field: header
      // ... other details
    });
```